# createAction ngrx methodology

Tags: ngrx

I've investigated quite a few different createAction methods and I'm confused on which one to use.

Let's say I have a username and password for login I've seen the following ways scattered across the internet:

```
export const myAction = createAction(
    '...',
    props<{ payload: { username: string, password: string }}>
);
```

vs

```
export const myAction = createAction(
    '...',
    props<{ username: string, password: string }>
);
```

I find the second one much cleaner because I could potentially have this:

```
export const myAction = createAction(
    '...',
    props<userModel>
);
```

The problem is when I log out the action the type is one of the properties in the second example which means I may run into conflicts if the userModel contains a type property. On the other side the first example would mean I'd have the word payload sprinkled all over my application which seems excessive.

Example in stackoverflow of the second example:

[How do you detect NgRx createAction duplicate types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437827/how-do-you-detect-ngrx-createaction-duplicate-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is when I log out the action the type is one of the properties in the second example which means I may run into conflicts if the userModel contains a type property

NgRx will warn you if this happens, this will throw an error and you won't be able to compile. The `payload` property is a pattern used before the `createAction` was introduced, that's why you will see a lot of examples with a `payload` property.

Comment: Right, so is the new pattern to have it or not have it?

Comment: I recommend not to use it

Comment: Haha, I really appreciate your answer... but do you recommend not to use payload? Or not to use the new pattern :)

Comment:  I recommend to not use payload, just add the properties on the action.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton! Side question, feel free to answer or not, I already appreciate the time you're taking. When dealing with effects and the action how would we isolate out the props we need? Basically drop the "type" on the action, is there some standard way to do that?

Comment: See https://timdeschryver.dev/snippets/destructure-an-object-to-remove-a-property